# Formatting string into indonesia currency

Tags: asp.net, format, currency, currency-formatting

I'm getting this problem when trying to show a label that contain a number of calculation of prices.

so this is my code:

```
   Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID")
    Label1.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:C2}", hrgemas5gr)
```

the result from that code is:

```
RP#.###.###,00
```

but, what I want is like this:

```
Rp #.###.###
```

what is wrong? or how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the currency symbol and use `{0:C}` instead of `{0:C2}`:

```vb
Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID")
Dim numberFormat As NumberFormatInfo = culture.NumberFormat.Clone()
numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "Rp&nbsp;" 'Unbreakable space after Rp
Label1.Text = String.Format(numberFormat, "{0:C}", hrgemas5gr)
```

On my system, I get `Rp` by default as the currency symbol, so I can simply append the space to it:

```vb
numberFormat.CurrencySymbol &= "&nbsp;"
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted (with the check mark) if it solved your problem.